# GPUImage with uiElementInput positioning

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm trying to define the uiElementInput (imageSequence that is an UIImageView) size and positioning without success.
The movie is being generated with the image stretched.

I'm stuck on this for a couple days.
Any help would be appreciate!

Here's what I have so far:

```
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = NO;
videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorRearFacingCamera = NO;

filter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];
[videoCamera addTarget:filter];
blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
[(GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *)blendFilter setMix:1.0];
[blendFilter forceProcessingAtSizeRespectingAspectRatio:CGSizeMake(148, 250)];

imageSequence = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 148, 250)];
imageSequence.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
uiElementInput = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:imageSequence];

filterTrans1 = [[GPUImageTransformFilter alloc] init];
[filterTrans1 forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(148, 250)];

[filter addTarget:blendFilter];

[filterTrans1 addTarget:blendFilter];

[uiElementInput addTarget:blendFilter];

pathToMovie = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"moviez.m4v"];
unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]);
movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(480.0, 320.0)];
[blendFilter addTarget:movieWriter];

__unsafe_unretained GPUImageUIElement *weakUIElementInput = uiElementInput;

[filter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput * filter, CMTime frameTime){
    if (imageIndex == 20)
        imageIndex = 1;

    if (imageFrames == 5)
    {
        imageFrames = 0;
        imageSequence.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 148, 250);
        imageSequence.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageSequence.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"testeImage%i", imageIndex]];
        [weakUIElementInput update];
        imageIndex++;
    }
    imageFrames++;
}];

[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
...
```